# function to exclude array object

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

i have this code for a rule engine i am creating

```
getSKULine = (s, priceList) ->
  rdb.getDiscountMap(s, priceList)
    .then (result) ->
      console.log result
      if result.cdLine is "T" and result.cdOver is "F" then result else null

exports.getRules = (user) ->
  if !user
    Promise.resolve null
  else
    priceList = user.company.opera.terms.priceList
    territory = user.company.opera.account.territory
    country = user.company.country
    emailId = user.emailId
    account = user.company._id
    trade_sector = user.company.trade_sector
    discountCache = {}
    cond = {
      'status': 'published'
      'type': 'price'
      "to" : { "$gte" : Date.now() }
      "unselPriceLists": { "$nin": [ priceList ] }
      "unselReps": { "$nin": [ territory ] }
      "unselCountries": { "$nin": [ country ] }
      "unselAccounts": { "$nin": [ account ] }
      "unselCompanyTypes": { "$nin": [ trade_sector ] }
    }
    Rule.findAllPr(cond)
    .then (rules) ->
      _.zipObject rules.map (r) ->
        skus = _.zipObject(r.skus.map((s) ->
          if getSKULine(s, priceList)
            [
              s
              r.discount
            ]
          else null
        ))
        extended = _.extend(discountCache, skus)
    .then (skus) ->
      discountCache
```

in the line `if getSKULine(s, priceList)` i am checking against a redis cache which has entry like

```
{ sku: 'SA61-MNA',
  priceList: 'DISTSD',
  quantity1: 1,
  quantity2: 10,
  quantity3: 50,
  price1: 263,
  price2: 228,
  price3: 208,
  cdLine: 'T',
  cdOver: 'T',
  cdFundec: 2 }
{ sku: 'SA61-MPL',
  priceList: 'DISTSD',
  quantity1: 1,
  quantity2: 10,
  quantity3: 50,
  price1: 263,
  price2: 228,
  price3: 208,
  cdLine: 'T',
  cdOver: 'T',
  cdFundec: 2 }
```

i want to only return an object where cdLine is 'T' and cdOver is 'F' but it doen not seem to work as my discountCache object still includes these line?

what am i missing, any advice is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you will want to use `Array.prototype.reduce` instead of map so that you can *conditionally* add the results returned by `getSKULine`. Something like this:

```
skus = _.zipObject (r.skus.reduce(((accum, s) ->
  obj = getSKULine(s, priceList)
  if obj? and obj.cdLine is 'T' and obj.cdOver is 'F'
    accum.push([s, r.discount)
  accum), [])
```

and now that you're using `reduce` instead of `map` you don't need the lodash function to convert the result:

```
skus = r.skus.reduce(((accum, s) ->
  obj = getSKULine(s, priceList)
  if obj? and obj.cdLine is 'T' and obj.cdOver is 'F'
    accum[s] = r.discount
  accum), {})
```

## EDIT

Sorry just realized that `getSKULine` returns a Promise rather than an object. That is why your original code doesn't work: you are mixing synchronous and async code. Since the function returns a Promise the result will always be truthy, your conditional filtering in `getSKULine` does nothing. In fact, that entire function is unnecessary. You will need to do something like this:

```
#map over the skus to get an array of Promises, use Promise.all
#to convert to a Promise of an array of objects from the Redis
#cache
skuLines = Promise.all(r.skus.map((s) -> rdb.getDiscountMap(s, priceList)));
result = skuLines.then((arr) -> arr.reduce(((accum, obj, i) ->

  #grabbing the original sku
  s = r.skus[i]

  #moved the filtering from getSKULine to here
  if obj? obj.cdLine is 'T' and obj.cdOver is 'F' then accum[s] = r.discount
  accum), {}))
```

To get the end object out of result you will need to call `then` on it. Something like `result.then((res) -> doStuff(res))`. Remember that you can't 'unbox' a Promise, you will always have to call the `then` method to get at the value inside. That's what was wrong with the original `getSKULines`, you thought you were returning `null` but since `then` automatically wraps the result in another Promise you were actually returning a *Promise* of `null`.

Comment: i tried this and i just get empty list or undefined.

Comment: The code I wrote in the second example (without lodash) will return an object. It may be empty, but it'll be an object. That said, if it is empty, then its because none of the calls to `getSKULine` returned something that passed the conditional checks. You can take them out to test. Also make sure that r.skus.length > 0, otherwise the code won't do anything.

Comment: i used your second code, but for `obj.cdLine` i get undefined, so the if obj? always returns an empty array

Comment: thanks for this, although i have one more question, the `result.then((res) -> doStuff(res))` is it right to add it within the loop for finding all published rules? as this creates duplicate entries depending on how many rules there are?

Comment: We're getting beyond the scope of the original question. Once again, you **cannot mix sync and async code**. Once you start using promises, you cannot expect their values to be there unless you are in a callback passed to `then`. Nor can you access them, unless (again) you're inside a callback passed to `then`. If you are expecting to synchronously loop over values that have been wrapped in promises, you will continue have the same problem that brought you here in the first place.